# How can I get the number of online users now in my app

Tags: android, api, android-studio

is there any website to get online users now in my app or any good idea?

I tried to using onStart and onDestory but do not work well Are there other ideas

Comment: do you have your own api server ?

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh yes I have server on GoDaddy

Comment: you can send online status to your server from your application base activity class's onStart() and inside the onStop() you can send the updated status to server.

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh I know but the problem how to refresh textview in all users when there a new update on server like firebase real time

Comment: for that just use firebase for maintaining you online status, and get the status for showing online real time status

Comment: firebase database is real time database it will reflect on your app also if it gets change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use [**Socket**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket) for more accurate data

This way your server-side and mobile app can maintain real-time comms, which can be used in more than just tracking who is online you can even track in which activity they users are.

if you want something with less code you can use **[fabric](https://www.fabric.io/)** KPI which can track alot more things like content view - Search - share -Rated content - etc.

**NOTE**
google bought fabric and right now they are working on migrating  all of fabric features to their firebase service.

Comment: anything that would be real time data is better for accurate statistics and socket is one of the most popular real-time connection

Comment: @hossamscott I should learn node.js to use socket ?

Comment: yes, if you don't know how to write node.js already and you are working alone on project or don't have the time, try fabric tool you don't need much coding ,everything can be done in less then 30 minute from my experience .